# UITabBarController with UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

i am trying to display a list on my first view  so added this in the first.h :

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface argospineFirstViewController : UIViewController
    <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
   {
NSMutableArray *Journals;
IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
    }

   @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *Journals;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *myTableView;
    @end
```

and then i added this on my first.m :

```
  @implementation argospineFirstViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
Journals=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"journal1",@"journal2",nil];
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 2;
 }
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.text=[Journals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;

}
```

I am newbie so i don't really know what kind of connections i have got to make, i am also using a storyboard with a tableview dropped on the first view.
is there something i have to add to the delegate?
Any help?
Thank you for your time

Comment: Have you made connections in your .xib file?

Comment: @M.Sharjeel i don't have any.xib file i am using a storyboard

Comment: Try my answer below and update me!

Comment: as a general comment, don't use capital letters for the first letter of a variable name.  Use journals instead of Journals for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not make property of your table view object.

Also,

in **viewDidLoad** method write:

```
myTableView.dataSource = self;
myTableView.delegate = self;
```

Tell me if it helps!

Comment: theoretically what are they supposed to do?

Comment: yes but not for a long time... i moved my table view to replace it better and i lost the result ... can this be related to the connections?

Comment: what are u doing now? Show latest snippet!

Comment: well actually i didn't do anything i just moved the tableview a little bit(drag and drop) in the storyboard i compiled again and it didn't work

Comment: i don't know how to set it because i don't understand how it works!!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the tableView in the storyboard.  You will see "delegate" and "dataSource" under Outlets.  Drag the bubble on the right of those to the view controller icon at the bottom of the view.  This will make your viewcontroller the delegate and datasource for the table view if you don't want to do it programmatically.

Comment: The view controller icon is now on the top of the viewcontroller in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Use initWithStyle instead of initWithFrame for creating your cell.

In your storyboard, select your table view and open the Connections Inspector. Make sure that the delegate and datasource connections are linked to your argospineFirstViewController object.

Answer (score 0):

in IBOutlet set delegete and datasource of the tableview to filesOwner

Comment: how can i do this?? is it possible to do it programmatically ?

Comment: [myTableView setDelegate:self];  [myTableView setDataSource:self];

Answer (score 0):

you use cell.text for show the data i think its not work in tableview just try this line:-

```
cell.textlabel.text=[yourArrayname objectatindex:index.row];
```

no need to connect delegate you already define in protocol.

Comment: cell.text works but it's not advised because it may be removed in the next versions